# Replacing characters in Python returns TypeError: string operation on non-string array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataframe 'data' and I want to replace all the punctuation marks in a given column with nothing (so I want to remove them).

Im using Python 3 and Pandas and Numpy to pre-format some text before working with a Neural Network.

```py
symbols = "!\"#$%&()*+-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\n"
dataClean = data['description']

for i in symbols:
    dataClean = np.char.replace(dataClean,i,"")
```

I expected that, for every item in dataClean (it goes from 0 to 2549), every string contained in each row got punctuation marks deleted. 
But I got this in return:

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-87-aa944ae6e61c> in <module>
      3 
      4 for i in symbols:
----> 5     dataClean = np.char.replace(dataClean,i,"")
      6 
      7 print(dataClean[2])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\defchararray.py in replace(a, old, new, count)
   1184     return _to_string_or_unicode_array(
   1185         _vec_string(
-> 1186             a, object_, 'replace', [old, new] + _clean_args(count)))
   1187 
   1188 

TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

Comment: Maybe you should use regex substitution.

Comment: `np.char` functions work on `numpy` arrays with string dtypes (e.g. `U4`).  Pandas uses `object` dtype for strings.  That is, pandas strings are regular Python strings.  So use string methods, not numpy ones.

Answer (score 3):

If `dataClean` is a Pandas Series of strings, you could use the `Series.str.translate` method:

```
symbols = "!\"#$%&()*+-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\n"
dataClean = data['description']
dataClean = dataClean.str.translate({ord(symbol):"" for symbol in symbols})
```

---

For example, suppose we had the DataFrame, `df`:

```
In [59]: df = pd.DataFrame({'data':['[Yes?]', '(No!)', 100]}); df
Out[59]: 
     data
0  [Yes?]
1   (No!)
2     100
```

Then we can make a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) mapping unicode ordinals to strings (or, in this case, the empty string):

```
In [52]: symbols = "!\"#$%&()*+-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\n"
In [57]: {ord(symbol):"" for symbol in symbols}
Out[57]: 
{33: '',
 34: '',
 ...
 126: '',
 10: ''}
```

Every unicode ordinal, or [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) which corresponds to a unicode character.
A Python3 string is a sequence of unicode characters. For each string in the Series, the `translate` method replaces each character in the string with the corresponding string given by the dict mapping.

```
In [60]: df['data'].str.translate({ord(symbol):"" for symbol in symbols})
Out[60]: 
0    Yes
1     No
2    NaN
Name: data, dtype: object
```

Notice that `translate` maps non-strings such as the `100` in the third row to `NaN`.

Comment: Just tried it. When executed it doesnt fail. But when I print any item from dataClean i get a "nan"

Comment: @Hessiann: My mistake. The keys in the dict passed to `translate` should be unicode *ordinals*.

Comment: Could you explain a little more please? Or show me with an example? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
symbols = "[!\"#$%&()*+-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\n]"
dataClean = dataClean.str.replace(symbols, "")
```

Comment: Just tried it. Code looks like this now:

symbols = "!\"#$%&()*+-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~\n"
dataClean = data['description']

dataClean = dataClean.str.replace(symbols, "")

Got this in return:

error: multiple repeat at position 9 (line 1, column 10)

Comment: add [ and ] around !\"#$%&()*+-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~\n